# Updating Search Suggestions

Tags: android, search-suggestion

My app uses a SearchView with custom suggestions. There are some fixed suggestions (recent searches and the like) but other suggestions have to be fetched through an HTTP request and populated once the request has returned. Every time the query text updates, I launch a new request based on the current query text (canceling any previous request in the process).

The problem is that sometimes the request returns but the results (which I've verified) don't show up in the suggestions list.

Is there any way that I can ensure that the suggestions are updated/displayed once the request returns?

Comment: provide more detail please

Comment: Trying to remember how I resolved this. I believe the issue was the lack of a proper bulk insert method in ContentProvider. The results would come back and be inserted using the faulty bulkInsert method, which would only show a few of the results.